# Why is kotlin stream evaluating an .all predicate to true where the first Iterable is empty

Tags: kotlin

I have a List of objects.
`importerResponse.applications` is empty (size=0)

This is my code:

```
        val isDeployed = importerResponse.applications
                .flatMap(Application::instances)
                .map(Instance::state)
                .all { state -> DEPLOYED == state }
```

`isDeployed` is true in this case. How can this be? I want it to resolve into false if `applications` is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you want that? All the elements in the collection satisfy your predicate.

You can check the documentation:
https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/all.html

If you want you can explicitly check for the collection being empty.

This should give you what you want:

````
val isDeployed = importerResponse.applications
                   .flatMap(Application::instances)
                   .map(Instance::state)
                   .count { state -> DEPLOYED == state } > 0```
````

Comment: how do they satisfy my predicate if the applications are empty? There is no state being deployed since the mapping can't even call those properties

Comment: Unfortunately the phrase `All the elements satisfy the predicate` is true.

Or, if you prefer, becase the documentation says so.

Answer (score 1):

The `all` method might be looking for any element that doesn't meet the condition, since you don't have any, it defaults to true.

You can achieve what you want by doing something similar to this:

```
val isDeployed = importerResponse.applications
            .flatMap(Application::instances)
            .map(Instance::state)
            .let { it.size() > 0 && it.all { state -> DEPLOYED == state } }
```

Note that `let` allows you to reuse the same expression without recalculating it twice.

Answer (score 0):

It can be a little bit confusing, why "any" returns "false" on empty collections, but "all" return true, because "all" seems to be more limiting than "any" (based on human language).

But if you ask as one example "if all persons in a room are male", than that's still true, if the room is empty. 0 out of 0 persons are ALL.

Comment: Yea but still I would go with "false" since ALL 0 persons can be everything - also not male... meh... confusing

Comment: That only means that "all are not male" is true too, not that "all are male" is false.